# Processing indicator does not work when reloading datatable jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, datatables

I'm customizing the datatable's loading indicator (customizing with a spinner - startLoadGlobal (SPINNER_DATA_TABLE_FINANCEIRO_CARREGAR_REGISTROS)) jquery that works correctly when I load the datatable for the first time. When I reload the datatable, the spinner no longer works because the datatable does not seem to trigger the processing mechanism.
In my case, the "processing" parameter should always be set to false so as not to hinder customization.

Does anyone know how to help me?

Thanks :)

DataTable:

```
function load_dtFinanceiroIndex() {
    var table = $("#dtFinanceiroIndex").DataTable({
        "info": true,
        "searching": true,
        "processing": false, // for show progress bar
        "serverSide": true, // for process server side
        "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
        "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
        "ordering": true, //Ativar/Desativar Ordenação de colunas 
        "order": [[1, "asc"]], //Ordenar da segunda coluna em diante para não atrapalhar a coluna [0] da seleção
        "ajax": {
            "url": '/financeiro-gerenciar/getFinanceiro',
            "data": function (d) {
                var formdata = $("#frm-pesquisa-avancada").serializeArray();
                var data = {};
                $(formdata).each(function (index, obj) {
                    data[obj.name] = obj.value;
                });

                d.financeiroPesquisaAvancadaViewModel = data;

            },
            "type": "POST",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columnDefs": [
            //Estilos Das Colunas
            { className: "align-center", "targets": [0] },
            { className: "align-center", "targets": [1] },
            { className: "align-left", "targets": [2] },
            { className: "align-left", "targets": [3] },
            { className: "align-left", "targets": [4] },
            { className: "align-center", "targets": [5] },
            { className: "align-center", "targets": [6] },

            //Largura das Colunas
            { width: 10, targets: 0 },
            { width: 130, targets: 1 },
            { width: 10, targets: 2 },
            { width: 10, targets: 3 },
            { width: 220, targets: 4 },
            { width: 10, targets: 5 },
            { width: 10, targets: 6 },
            { "orderable": false, "targets": 0 }
        ],
        "columns": [
            {
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<td><span class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default"><input class="selectable-item" type="checkbox" id="' + full.id + '" ><label></label></span></td>';
                }
            },
            {
                data: 'FinanceiroTipoDescricao',
                title: 'Tipo',
                autoWidth: true,
                render: function (data, type, item) {
                    return item.financeiroTipoDescricao;
                }
            },
            {
                data: 'NumeroDocumento',
                title: 'Número do Doc.',
                autoWidth: true,
                render: function (data, type, item) {
                    return item.numeroDocumento;
                }
            },
            {
                data: 'ValorDocumento',
                title: 'Valor do Doc.',
                autoWidth: true,
                render: function (data, type, item) {
                    const value = parseFloat(item.valorDocumento);
                    if (!value) return 0;
                    return "R$ " + value.toLocaleString('pt-br', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 });
                }
            },
            {
                data: 'NomeRazao',
                title: 'Cliente/Fornecedor',
                autoWidth: true,
                render: function (data, type, item) {
                    return item.nomeRazao;
                }
            },
            {
                data: 'FinanceiroSituacaoDescricao',
                title: 'Situação',
                autoWidth: true,
                render: function (data, type, item) {
                    return item.financeiroSituacaoDescricao;
                }
            },
            {
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                    return '<div class="btn-group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown" role="group"><a data-id="' + full.id + '" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-default btn-outline btn-editar-financeiro" title="Visualizar/Editar"><i class="icon wb-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><a data-id="' + full.id + '" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-default btn-outline btn-excluir-financeiro" title="Excluir"><i class="icon wb-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><div class="btn-group" role="group"><a title="Mais Ações" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="exampleGroupDrop2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="icon wb-grid-4" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="exampleGroupDrop2" role="menu"><a class="dropdown-item viewbutton" data-modal-financeiro-history="" data-id="' + full.id + '" role="menuitem"><i class="icon wb-time" aria-hidden="true"></i>Histórico</a></div></div></div>';
                }
            }
        ],
        "language": {
            "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
            "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sInfoThousands": ".",
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultados por página",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
            "sProcessing": startLoadGlobal(SPINNER_DATA_TABLE_FINANCEIRO_CARREGAR_REGISTROS),
            "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
            "sSearch": "Pesquisar",
            "searchPlaceholder": "Digite algo...",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sNext": "Próximo",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                "sFirst": "Primeiro",
                "sLast": "Último"
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
            }
        }
    });

    //Evento disparado depois que a table for desenhada
    table.on('draw', function () {
        stopLoadGlobal();
    });    
}
```

HTML:

```
<table id="dtFinanceiroIndex" class="table-responsive-xl table table-striped table-bordered center-header table-vcenter" cellspacing="0">
    <thead class="bg-blue-grey-100">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <span class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default">
                    <input id="dt-financeiro-selectable-all" class="selectable-all" type="checkbox">
                    <label></label>
                </span>
            </th>
            <th>
                Tipo de Controle Financeiro
            </th>
            <th>
                Núm. do Documento
            </th>
            <th>
                Valor do Documento
            </th>
            <th>
                Cliente/Fornecedor
            </th>
            <th>
                Situação
            </th>
            <th>
                Ações
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Spinner- JS:

```
function startLoadGlobal(text) {
    if (text === '')
        text = "Carregando...";
    
    $("#spinner-global").text(text);
    $("#spinner-global").show();
}

function stopLoadGlobal() {
    $("#spinner-global").text('Carregando...');
    $("#spinner-global").hide();
}
```

Spinner CSS:

```
#spinner-global {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    /*z-index: 9999;*/
    z-index: 999999999;
    display: none;
    font-size: larger;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100vh;
    padding-top: 45px;
}


    #spinner-global::after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        margin: -36px auto 0 -36px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: black;
        border-top-color: transparent;
        border-width: 4px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        -webkit-animation: spin .8s linear infinite;
        animation: spin .8s linear infinite;
        -webkit-animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
        -moz-animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
        -o-animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
        animation: rotation .6s infinite linear;
        border-left: 6px solid rgba(0,174,239,.15);
        border-right: 6px solid rgba(0,174,239,.15);
        border-bottom: 6px solid rgba(0,174,239,.15);
        border-top: 6px solid rgba(0,174,239,.8);
        border-radius: 50%;
    }

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes rotation {
    from {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    to {
        -moz-transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}

@-o-keyframes rotation {
    from {
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    to {
        -o-transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}

@keyframes rotation {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    to {
        transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
```

Reload Datatable:

```
$("#btn-pesquisar-painel-financeiro").on("click", function (e) {
   $('#dtFinanceiroIndex').DataTable().ajax.reload();
});
```

Comment: How are you reloading the datatable?

Comment: I updated the post ... I'm updating from a button.

Comment: Try setting this variable in the global scope var table =  $('#dtFinanceiroIndex').DataTable({});  And, then try table.ajax.reload();  You might also need this line of code at the top of your load_dtFinanceiroIndex function right before you populate the table. table.destroy();

Comment: It didn't work @jqueryHtmlCSS ... the curious thing is that if I change the "processing" parameter to true, it works, but in my case, it needs to be set to false, because I'm customizing it with a spinner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by validating the datatable event "processing.dt", according to the help of the Data Table forum: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/39641/processing-events.

Solution:

```
table.on('processing.dt', function (e, settings, processing) {       
    if (processing) {
        startLoadGlobal(SPINNER_PESQUISANDO_REGISTROS);
    } else {
        stopLoadGlobal();
    }
});
```